# Django deployment with gunicorn issue

Tags: python, django, deployment, nginx, gunicorn

I am referring this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/

for gunicorn and django deployment.

I am a bit confused with the tutorial

> So for a typical Django project, invoking gunicorn would look like:
>
> gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application

My django project is in /home/joe/fancyproject_dir

What would be the command line to invoke gunicorn for my project ?

'joe' is my username

Would it be

> gunicorn fancyproject_dir.wsgi:application

or

> gunicorn joe.wsgi:application

or something else?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gunicorn command expect the argument to be `<python package>:<wsgi identifier>`, so following this common project structure:

```
my_project_folder
|-my_project
| |-__init__.py
| |-wsgi.py
| |-settings.py
```

the command would be `my_project.wsgi:application`, the trick is identifying the package by looking for the `__init__.py` file.